# AWS SQS: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMerge?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, noclassdeffounderror, fasterxml

I am trying to a message to SQS in my Java code as follows:

```
public void pushToSQS(){

    String queueURL = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/205135634997/myQueue.fifo";
    
    try {

        final AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        sqs.sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest(queueURL,
                "test message"));

    } catch (final AmazonServiceException e) {
        log.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However at line: `final AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();`

I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMerge
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonMerge
```

I have added the following to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.86</version>
        </dependency>
```

Below are all the `jackson` dependencies in the project:
[image]

In `mvn` dependency tree I can see:

```
+- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:2.3.5.Final:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.5.jboss-1:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.txw2:txw2:jar:20110809:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.5:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:jar:0.6:provided
[INFO] \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]       +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.3:provided


[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: You need a dependency on the Jackson Annotation library.

Comment: OK can you give mvn link?

Comment: I have added that and now am getting the error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/SchemePortResolver

Comment: It looks like aws-java-sdk-sqs doesn't declare the dependencies it needs, or maybe there is some other Amazon dependency that you should import to get those. You might want to complain to Amazon. The error itself suggests that you need to declare a dependency on Apache HTTP client.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with your local setup. Adding the dependency above, it added these child dependencies:

aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.813.jar
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.813.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
httpclient-4.5.9.jar
httpcore-4.4.11.jar
commons-codec-1.11.jar
ion-java-1.0.2.jar
jackson-databind-2.6.7.3.jar
jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar
jackson-core-2.6.7.jar
jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar
joda-time-2.8.1.jar
jmespath-java-1.11.813.jar

Comment: how can I check? I still cannot solve the issue

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree`. Search for jackson annotation there. Tell us what you see.

Comment: You seem to have a version conflict. Jackson databind appears twice with different versions.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski I have added more information to the question now with the mvn dependency tree

Comment: @java12399900 Can you please provide the complete error trace and pom.xml for better understanding of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have jackson twice. Consider this:

```
+- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO] \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:jar:3.0.19.Final:provided
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]       +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.6.3:provided
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.3:provided
```

and this:

```
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
```

Please drop the top level dependency to `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6` and see if it works.

Comment: How do you mean the top level dependency? What to change in pom.xml?

Comment: Look for `jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6` in your pom.xml. Try to remove it. If this does not work, replace version with 2.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

As per error, the code is trying to load **'com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMerge'** **which is not available in 'jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.3'**. And as per maven dependency shared above, version 2.6.3 of Jackson libraries are being referred.

But the **required class present in version 2.9.6**. So suggest to use 2.9.6. Recommend to use jackson-databind and jackson-core also with version 2.9.6.

Answer (score 1):

I see there are two versions of **jackson-databind** and **jackson-annotations**.
In version 2.9.2+ version JsonMerge is available in jackson-annotations.

Use maven dependency tree using **mvn dependency:tree** find and exclude the older versions of jackson-annotations and jackson:databind